# InlineKeyboardMarkup don't work in pyrogram

Tags: bots, telegram, pyrogram

I'm trying to send message with inline keyboard:

```
await user_bot.send_message(
                    user_id, "This is a InlineKeyboardMarkup example",
                    reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([[
                        InlineKeyboardButton('Смотреть онлайн!', url='http://f1.ikino.site/index.php?do=search', callback_data='watch online'),
                        InlineKeyboardButton('Поиск фильмов!', url='http://f1.ikino.site/index.php?do=search',
                                            callback_data='search films',)
                    ]])
                )
```

But it do not wokring!!! Can anybody help me?
Message was send, but without inlineKeyboard

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're logged in as a user, seeing your `user_bot` variable.

Users cannot attach a Keyboard (Reply or Inline). Use a normal Bot.

Comment: Bot can't send a message to another Bot. Because of this problem I became to use pyrogram.